# if i don't want to use dsl to write the code which build connection between jms and spring integration channel, how does it do

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch

In this link, the author use java domain specific language to build connection from spring integration channel to activeMQ. If i don't want to use java dsl and I just want to use general java method. how should I do?

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outboundFlow(ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(requests())
            .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory).destination("requests"))
            .get();
}
```

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/remotepartitioning/aggregating/WorkerConfiguration.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Jms.outboundAdapter(connectionFactory)` is a syntax sugar wrapper around `JmsSendingMessageHandler`.

The `.handle()` is an equivalent of the `@ServiceActivator`.

So, what you need with plain Java is like this:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel="requests")
public MessageHandler jmsMessageHandler((ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
   JmsSendingMessageHandler handler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory));
   handler.setDestinationName("requests");
   return handler;
}
```

See some explanation in the Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips

And more about `JmsSendingMessageHandler`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/jms.html#jms-outbound-channel-adapter